# Cordova dynamically created buttons don't work on iOS but work on Android

Tags: cordova

I can't get some dynamically created buttons to work on iOS using Cordova. The same code runs fine on Android.

```
window.onload = function(){

     $("#runBtn").on("click", function(){

          addBtns();

     });

      $("#parentDiv").on("click", ".dynamicBtn", function(){

          alert($(this).val());

     });

}

var addBtns = function(){

     for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){

         var classOfBtn = "dynamicBtn";
         var val = "button" + i;

           $("#parentDiv).append("<button class='" + classOfBtn + "'>" + val + "</button>");

     }

}
```

I did read that adding the `css cursor:pointer;` to the button would help but this didn't fix it.

Comment: Hi Lee, I fixed that code already, hang on - let me fix it again. Code formatting here uses Markdown, not `<code>` tags.

Comment: I've rolled back to my last edit. Btw, when editing, keep an eye out for messages to say that another edit has been performed - at that point it is best to copy what you have to the clipboard, back out of the edit, and selectively reapply what you have if necessary.

Comment: Thanks halfer. This is my first time here didn't realise someone could edit the code for me. Sorry if I kept changing it.

Comment: No worries, yes we have reputation-based editing privileges here. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) is a good introduction.